# Initializing Mats

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have the following simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    Mat1b image;
    image = imread( argv[1], IMREAD_GRAYSCALE );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }

    int rows= image.rows;
    int cols= image.cols;

    Mat1b taped_image(rows + 32, cols + 32);
    Mat1b pyr_image = taped_image(Rect{16, 16, cols, rows});//<----HERE!!
 //   int t=image.type();

 //   Mat taped_image(rows + 32, cols + 32,t);
 //   Mat pyr_image = taped_image(Rect{16, 16, cols, rows});

    cv::copyMakeBorder(image, taped_image, 16, 16, 16, 16, BORDER_REFLECT_101 + BORDER_ISOLATED);



   // namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   // imshow("Display Image", image);
    imshow("Tapped image",taped_image);
    imshow("Display Image", pyr_image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, I got the taped image in a window "Tapped image" (as expected) and a black and white noise image in "Display Image. (When I used Mat instead of Mat1b the image was all black)

However I have the exact same thing in a much complex program and in that program apparently pyr_image got the original image.(as if it were a pointer)

Also in the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa7ec97373406215f2d4bc72cc1d27036) Mat definition 16 it says

> Array that (as a whole or partly) is assigned to the constructed
> matrix. No data is copied by these constructors. Instead, the header
> pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with
> it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented. So, when you modify
> the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also modify the
> corresponding elements of m . If you want to have an independent copy
> of the sub-array, use Mat::clone() .

So it seems that taped_image and pyr_image are associated. My questions are

1. Why it appears as noise to me?
2. Are pyr_image and image associated? (therefore having the same data)?

Comment: You should execute `cv::copyMakeBorder` before `Mat1b pyr_image = taped_image(Rect{16, 16, cols, rows});`. (I can't give a complete answer right now). Please add `c++` tag.

Comment: At the moment `pyr_image` is created, it shares its buffer with `taped_image`. Then your call to `copyMakeBorder` breaks this link, because the destination size doesn't match (`taped_image` is only 32 pixels larger than `image` in each direction, but you add a 32 pixel border on each edge, which adds up to 64 pixels in each direction). This leaves `pyr_image` still pointing to a buffer which you never set to anything.

Comment: @Rotem not necessarily. IMHO the problem is the inconsistency (along with a pile of magic numbers). First the code acts as if OP wanted to add 16 pixel border on each side, and then they suddenly add 32 pixels.

Comment: @DanMašek the magic numbers are a simplification of the original code I am debugging. The use of 16 and 32 is because it seems that taped_image has 32 more pixels than the original. But the original is in the center

Comment: @DanMašek I made a mistake with the pixels, and corrected the question. With that now both images point to the same place. Thanks for the help!